# Ruby marshal on a string differs from marshal on a symbol converted to a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In both of these cases:

```
a = Marshal.dump(:rent_active_on.to_s)
b = Marshal.dump('rent_active_on')

a = Marshal.dump(String(:rent_active_on))
b = Marshal.dump(String('rent_active_on'))
```

a is not equal to b. The end values are ALMOST the same:

```
 > a = Marshal.dump(:rent_active_on.to_s)
 => "\x04\bI\"\x13rent_active_on\x06:\x06EF" 
 > b = Marshal.dump('rent_active_on')
 => "\x04\bI\"\x13rent_active_on\x06:\x06ET"
```

The difference is the very last character. The 'F' vs the 'T'. I can't find any way to make them yield the same result. I'm totally confused... what's going on here?

Using Ruby 2.6.1

Comment: I'm curious why you should want or expect `a` to equal `b` considering that `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(:rent_active_on.to_s)) == Marshal.load(Marshal.dump('rent_active_on')) #=> true ("rent_active_on")`. Isn't this equality all that you care about?

Comment: My use case is taking a hash, recursively sorting and stringifying it's keys, then running the marshal output through MD5. The incoming hash is a set of parameters, and the MD5 is part of a Redis lookup key. The idea is that if I later call a method with a similar hash, put with symbolized keys instead of string keys, I can run the new hash through the same routine to see if I have a cached value I can look up. So basically, I needed two hashes to produce the same result when ran as follows: `Digest::MD5.hexdigest(Marshal.dump(some_hash.deep_stringify_keys.sort_by_key))`

Comment: Just for information: On my Ruby (MRI 2.6.4), `Marshal.dump('rent_active_on')` returns just `"\x04\b"\x13rent_active_on"`. No _ET_ added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow `Marshal.dump(:rent_active_on.to_s)` doesn't produce the same output as `Marshal.dump('rent_active_on')`, but `Marshal.dump("#{:rent_active_on}")` does, try interpolating instead:

```
Marshal.dump("#{:rent_active_on}") # "\x04\bI\"\x13rent_active_on\x06:\x06ET"
Marshal.dump('rent_active_on')     # "\x04\bI\"\x13rent_active_on\x06:\x06ET"
```

Or you could instead use symbols:

```
Marshal.dump(:rent_active_on)         # "\x04\b:\x13rent_active_on"
Marshal.dump('rent_active_on'.to_sym) # "\x04\b:\x13rent_active_on"
```

Comment: That seems to fix it! Also, a co worker managed to find an alternative method in an IRC channel right about the same time I saw your answer:

`Marshal.dump(:rent_active_on.to_s.encode('UTF-8')) == Marshal.dump('rent_active_on')`

Super weird behavior that really gave us the runaround this morning. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Nice! Any concrete answer about the output difference when using `symbol.to_s` ?

Comment: I only just now realized you had included the second idea of using symbols instead of strings. Sure enough, that would have worked as well and sidestepped the whole issue! Still, interesting discovery about the issue with strings. See the alternate answer given by @shiny-objects for the explanation. He's the co worker that helped figure out the underlying issue.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an encoding issue. Either forcing the encoding:

```
a = Marshal.dump(:rent_active_on.to_s.encode('UTF-8'))
b = Marshal.dump('rent_active_on'.encode('UTF-8'))
a == b # true
```

Or interpolate:

```
a = Marshal.dump("#{:rent_active_on}")
b = Marshal.dump('rent_active_on')
a == b # true
```

If your editor is using, say, ASCII encoding then your symbols will be ASCII encoded. If your system locale is using UTF8, your strings will be encoded in UTF8.

So unless your editor's encoding and your system's encoding are the same this will happen. We tested it on a few systems ranging from ruby 2.5.5 to 2.7.1, and it *only* worked on a 2.7.0 machine that was set up to always use UTF8 (according to the system's admin)

Generally you don't want to count on binary encoding of an object to be in any way predictable - bytecode changes all the time, locale settings can mess with it, etc. That looks like what's happening here.